# Why do I sometimes get errors when exporting 3D graphics which have been translated or scaled?

Tags: export, graphics3d, warning-messages

*Update notice: The expression returned by `"Faces"` changed in V11, so an alternative for V11 has been included.*

When I try and export 3D graphics, I get an error if some of the graphics complexes are translated. For example:

```
r1 = PolyhedronData["RhombicDodecahedron", "Faces"];           (* works in V10 *)
r1 = PolyhedronData["RhombicDodecahedron", "GraphicsComplex"]; (* fix for V11 *)

trans = 2 Table[
    Mean[PolyhedronData["RhombicDodecahedron", "VertexCoordinates"][[
      n]]], {n, PolyhedronData["RhombicDodecahedron", "FaceIndices"]}];

r2 = Table[
   Translate[r1, n], {n, 
    Table[Accumulate[RandomChoice[trans, m]], {m, 6}]}];

exp = Graphics3D[r2, Boxed -> False, SphericalRegion -> True];

Export["rhomdod2.obj", exp]
```

gives the errors

> Export::type: Graphics3D cannot be exported to the OBJ format. >>
>   Export::type: RuleDelayed cannot be exported to the OBJ format. >>

I never get these errors when I just export a single object or an untranslated object.

Comment: It has seemed to me that transformations are not implemented for all export formats.  I don't know for sure whether that is the case, but, if so, it is probably version-dependent, too.

Comment: Note to site users: The OP's code produced valid graphics before V11.  Now it's broken.  Use `"GraphicsComplex"` in place of `"Faces"` for V11.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If, as I suspect, exporting to `"OBJ"` does not support geometric transformations, one fix is to convert your graphics to "normal" graphics.  (I wish `Normal` would do this, perhaps via an option.)

Here is a quick example of how to do this.  To code it up in full generality means handling all of the graphics primitives and all the transformations (and transforming the `VertexNormals`, too, I suppose).  I'll restrict my focus to the OP's specific example. (*Update notice: I simplified the code a bit. See edit history.*)

```
ClearAll[normify, xfcoords, ixfcoords];
normify[Translate[g_, v : {__?NumericQ}]] := normify[Translate[g, {v}]];
normify[Translate[g_, v_?MatrixQ]] := xfcoords[g, TranslationTransform[#]] & /@ v;
normify[g_] := g;

SetAttributes[xfcoords, Listable];
xfcoords[g_, xf_] := ixfcoords[g, xf];
ixfcoords[(obj : GraphicsComplex | Polygon | Line | Point)[coords_, rest___], xf_] := 
  obj[xf[coords], rest];
ixfcoords[g_, xf_] := g;
```

Example:

```
normalexp = normify //@ exp
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
FreeQ[normalexp, Translate]
(*  True  *)
```

It exports without error and creates a file, but I don't know how to check the output.

```
Export["/tmp/rhomdod2.obj", normalexp]
(*  "/tmp/rhomdod2.obj"  *)
```

Comment: I tested your code and don't  seems to work? My example:`pts = {{1, 1, 1}, {3, 3, 3}};
test = Graphics3D[Translate[Cuboid[], pts]]` on MMA `11.3`

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk I don't have V11.3 yet.  It works for me in V11.2 if I add `Cuboid` to the alternatives of geometric objects that `ixfcoords` recognizes. One would have to do this for `Sphere` and whatever other objects you have. -- Also `PolyhedronData["RhombicDodecahedron", "Faces"]` has changed from V10 to V11. Now it no longer returns a `GraphicsComplex`. It's very discouraging working with *M* sometimes. Sometimes I'll get getting prepared for class just to find that at some point in the last year, they've broken a demonstration that I wrote three years before and worked just fine.

Comment: Instead `Cuboid[]` I used `PolyhedronData["Cube", "GraphicsComplex"]`   and works fine now on MMA `11.3`. Thanks a lot `:)`

Answer (score 5):

*Here is an alternate approach to eliminating [`Translate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Translate) from [`Graphics3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D) objects.*

It seems that [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal) has not been taught how to handle [`Translate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Translate) objects with multiple translation vectors. So, you can work around this problem by threading the last argument of [`Translate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Translate) before using [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal). Here is a function to do this:

```
normalize[g_Graphics3D] := Normal[
    g /. t:Translate[_, {__List}] :> Thread[t, List, -1]
]
```

Using the simple example from the comment to @Michael's answer:

```
test = Graphics3D[Translate[Cuboid[], {{1,1,1}, {3,3,3}}]];
normalize[test] //InputForm
```

> Graphics3D[{Cuboid[{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}], Cuboid[{3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4}]}]

Using the more complicated OP example:

```
GraphicsRow[{exp, normalize[exp]}]
```

[image]

The output looks the same, and the normalized version is free of [`Translate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Translate):

```
FreeQ[normalize[exp], Translate]
```

> True

If you don't mucking about with the internals of Mathematica, you can instead teach [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal) how to handle these types of [`Translate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Translate) objects:

```
Unprotect[Internal`GeometricTransformation3D];
With[{gt = Internal`GeometricTransformation3D},
    gt[t:Translate[_, {__List}], r__] := gt[Thread[t, List, -1], r]
]
Protect[Internal`GeometricTransformation3D];
```

Then:

```
Normal[
    Graphics3D[Translate[Cuboid[{0,0,0}], {{1,1,1}, {3,3,3}}]]
]//InputForm
```

> Graphics3D[{Cuboid[{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}], Cuboid[{3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4}]}]