# Rotated ellipsoid exporting gives Export::type warning

Tags: graphics3d, export, 3d-printing

I tried to export the following model for 3D printing but failed:

```
model = 
 Graphics3D[
    Table[
      {Rotate[
        Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {4, 2, 3}],     
        i*Pi/(30/2) + Pi/180, {0, 0, 1}  
      ]}, 
      {i, 30} 
    ]
 ];

Export["test.obj", model]
```

> Export::type: Graphics3D cannot be exported to the OBJ format.
>
> Export::type: RuleDelayed cannot be exported to the OBJ format.

[image]

Is there any problem with my code? I found that if I use `Cylinder` or `Cuboid` instead of `Ellipsoid`, the model will be exported without any warning, why?

Comment: Isn't this precisely the same problem you outlined in [your previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/194423/27951) a few hours ago?

Comment: @MarcoB These two question have some similarities, but they are not the same problem. I just want to find a easy way to solve these two questions. Thank you!

Comment: The best way to do it might depend on what you want to do with the exported model.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I want to do 3D printing, but there's no format that I can export successfully. I want to find a useful way by code.

Comment: This isn't the first example in which `GeometricTransformation` causes trouble when exporting. (Another example I can find at the moment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63173/1871 )  It should be easier to find a workaround in this case, given rotated ellipsoid is not hard to generate without `Rotate`.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks so much! I found another example may help solving this problem: [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101302), they "normify" Translate, and that really did work. So can I "normify" Rotate like that?  I‘m not very good at writing code, and I hope you can take a look. Sincere thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The best workaround I can think out at the moment is to turn to `RegionPlot3D`.

To plot ellipsoid with `RegionPlot3D`, we need formula for general ellipsoid, which has been mentioned in the **Details** of document of `Ellipsoid`:

$$(x-p).{\Sigma^{-1 }}.(x-p)\leq 1$$

where $\Sigma$ is weight matrix, which can be generated with the help of `TransformedRegion`:

```
mat = TransformedRegion[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {4, 2, 3}], 
                        RotationTransform[k Pi/(30/2) + Pi/180, {0, 0, 1}]][[2]]
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  16 \cos ^2\left(\frac{\pi  k}{15}+\frac{\pi }{180}\right)+4 \sin ^2\left(\frac{\pi  k}{15}+\frac{\pi }{180}\right) & 12 \cos \left(\frac{\pi  k}{15}+\frac{\pi }{180}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  k}{15}+\frac{\pi }{180}\right) & 0 \\
>  12 \cos \left(\frac{\pi  k}{15}+\frac{\pi }{180}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  k}{15}+\frac{\pi }{180}\right) & 4 \cos ^2\left(\frac{\pi  k}{15}+\frac{\pi }{180}\right)+16 \sin ^2\left(\frac{\pi  k}{15}+\frac{\pi }{180}\right) & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 9 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

So the inequality representing the region is

```
expr = Or @@ Table[{x, y, z}.Inverse@mat.{x, y, z} <= 1 // Evaluate, {k, 30}];
```

`expr` is so large a symbolic expression, thus we compile it to speed up plotting:

```
cf = Compile[{x, y, z}, Evaluate@expr, 
             RuntimeOptions -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}];

(gra = RegionPlot3D[cf[x, y, z], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, Mesh -> None, 
                    PlotPoints -> 100]) // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Finally discretize `gra` and export (directly exporting `gra` is OK, but it takes `89.2224` seconds to finish):

```
disgra = gra // DiscretizeGraphics; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {3.33076, Null} *)

Export["test.obj", disgra] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.02844, "test.obj"} *)
```

The biggest advantage of this approach is, the quality of the generated mesh seems to be good:

```
Show[disgra, PlotRange -> {-5, 0}]
```

[image]

```
FindMeshDefects@disgra
```

[image]

So the generated .obj file should be suitable for 3D printing.

---

Indeed, it's  suitable for 3D printing:

[image]

Comment: Here is another way to compute `mat`: `mat = With[{θ = i*Pi/(30/2) + Pi/180}, RotationMatrix[θ, {0, 0, 1}].DiagonalMatrix[{4, 2, 3}^2].RotationMatrix[-θ, {0, 0, 1}]]` Recognizing that this is effectively an eigendecomposition, the inverse is then easy to assemble: `With[{θ = i*Pi/(30/2) + Pi/180}, RotationMatrix[θ, {0, 0, 1}].DiagonalMatrix[1/{4, 2, 3}^2].RotationMatrix[-θ, {0, 0, 1}]]`

Comment: Thank you very much! I need to learn more to understand these codes. Thank you  for your help to me all the time. I won't be able to solve any problems without your help, so thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution of the underlying problem but a way to circumvent it.

```
k = 30;
α = Pi/(k/2);
m = 360/(2 Pi/α);
n = 180;

f = {ϕ, θ} \[Function] {4 Cos[ϕ] Cos[θ], 2 Sin[ϕ] Cos[θ], 3 Sin[θ]};
pts0 = f @@@ Tuples[{
      Subdivide[-.5 Pi, .5 Pi, n],
      Subdivide[-1. α, 1. α, m]
      }][[All, {2, 1}]];
A = RotationMatrix[-N@α, {0, 0, 1}];
pts = (Join @@ NestList[#.A &, pts0, k - 1]);
polys = Mod[
   MeshCells[ArrayMesh[ConstantArray[1, {m, (k + 1) n}]], 2, "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]],
   Length[pts], 1];

plot = Graphics3D[{
    EdgeForm[],
    GraphicsComplex[pts, Polygon[polys]]
    },
   PlotRange -> All
   ];
R = DiscretizeGraphics@plot

Export["test.obj", R]
```

[image]

There are several problems with your approach. They are not problems by themself but they make it hard for Mathematica to do what you want.

1. You utilize `GeometricTransformation`s  and as xzczd pointed out the `Export` does not like it.
2. Contrary to `Line` or `Triangle`, `Ellipsoid` is a primitive that is not natively supported by the OBJ format. *Mathematica* has to discretize the `Ellipsoid`s first (i.e. approximate by triangle meshes).
3. Although we see only the pumpkin-shaped surface, most part of the overall geometry is hidden in the interior. With `Show[model,PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {0, 4}}]` you can see that it is quite a mess. Upon `Export`, all this mess has also to be discretized. Maybe the many self intersections of the geometry cause a problem. And you 3D printer software also won't like it. Moreover `DiscretizeGraphics` cannot handle `Ellipsoid` primitives; `DiscretizeGraphics[model]` just returns `EmptyRegion[3]`.

This first of these problems could be avoided as follows:

```
center = {0, 0, 0};
quadric = DiagonalMatrix[{4, 2, 3}^2];
model = Graphics3D[
  Table[
   translation = {0., 0., 0.};
   rotation = RotationMatrix[i*Pi/(30/2) + Pi/180, {0, 0, 1}];
   Ellipsoid[center + translation, rotation.quadric.Inverse[rotation]],
   {i, 30}]
  ]
```

But still, `Export` cannot handle it correctly because of the other two problems.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting a feasible way to circumvent it! I get another problem: `model = Graphics3D[Table[{Rotate[Translate[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {4, 2, 3}], {10, 0, 0}], i*Pi/(30/2) + Pi/180, {0, 0, 1}]}, {i, 30}]]` If I want to translate each ellipsoid like this, how can I do it in your code? I‘m not very good at writing code, so I hope you can reply to me when you are not busy. Sincere thanks!

Comment: I found another example may help solving this problem: [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101302), they "normify" Translate, and that really did work. So can I "normify" Rotate like that? I hope you can take a look. Thanks!