# Smoothing the Region？

Tags: regions, mesh, visualization, 3d-printing

There is a 2D Pi

[image]

I successed transformed it to 3D.

```
extrudeImage[image_] := 
  Block[{res, img}, 
  img = DeleteSmallComponents[Binarize[image, 0.9], 500];
  res = ImageMesh[img];
  RegionProduct[res, Line[{{0.}, {10.}}]]]

img = DeleteBorderComponents@
        ImageResize[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM0gC.png"], 100];
r = Region[extrudeImage@img, Axes -> True, 
        AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}];
r = TransformedRegion[r, TranslationTransform[-RegionCentroid@r]]
```

[image]

I tried to rotate it to create a more 3D Pi, but the surface seemed to be too rough, MMA can't export STL format.

```
RegionUnion@
 Table[TransformedRegion[r, RotationTransform[i, {0, 1, 0}]], {i, 0, 
 Pi/3, Pi/10}]
Export["test.stl", %]
```

[image]

How to make the surface smooth so that 3D printer can be used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need `DiscretizeRegion` and `RepairMesh`:

```
r = Region[extrudeImage@img, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}];
r2 = TransformedRegion[r, TranslationTransform[-RegionCentroid@r]];

r3 = DiscretizeRegion@r2 // RepairMesh

rfinal = RegionUnion@
  Table[TransformedRegion[r3, RotationTransform[i, {0, 1, 0}]], 
        {i, 0, Pi/3, Pi/30}] // RepairMesh; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {117.008, Null} *)

Export["testfinal.stl", rfinal]
```

---

### Update

`DiscretizeRegion` turns out to be unnecessary, because the output of `extrudeImage` is already a `MeshRegion`, so we just need:

```
r = extrudeImage@img

r2 = TransformedRegion[r, TranslationTransform[-RegionCentroid@r]]

r3 = 
   RegionUnion@
    Table[TransformedRegion[r2 // RepairMesh, RotationTransform[i, {0, 1, 0}]], {i, 0, 
      Pi/3, Pi/75}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.296961, Null} *)

Export["test3.stl", r3]
```

[image]

Notice the last `RepairMesh` has also been taken away, because `r3 == RepairMesh@r3` turns out to be `True`.

Comment: Thank you! May be the quanlity can be improved by `rnew = ImageMesh@RegionImage[rfinal];`, but too slow.

Comment: @partida I guess something like `{i, 0, Pi/3, Pi/75}` should improve the quality, but repairing this is again slow. (The last `RepairMesh` might not be necessary though. You may check if the model created without the last `RepairMesh` is defectless in the preview of 3D printer. )

Comment: However `RepairMesh` effects the dimension of Region! try `RegionDimension@RepairMesh@DiscretizeRegion@r2` and `RegionDimension@DiscretizeRegion@r2`

Comment: @partida That should not be a problem. The `RegionDimension` of `disgra` [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/194505/1871) is also `2`, but I still manage to print it.

Comment: However the `rfinal` can't be processed in 3D again. try `RegionIntersection[rfinal, 
 Region@Cylinder[{{0, -30, 0}, {0, 30, 0}}, 20]]`

Comment: @partida Just repair the `Cylinder`: `DiscretizeRegion@Cylinder[{{0, -30, 0}, {0, 30, 0}}, 20] // RepairMesh`

Comment: Not worked. The output is `BooleanRegion[#1 && #2 &, {reg1, reg2}]` not 3D region

Comment: @partida That's a bit surprising. I think a separate question should be asked to address this issue.

Comment: Ok, I will open a new question, and also discuss this problem

Comment: @partida `DiscretizeRegion` is not necessary, and the code is much faster now. See my update.

Comment: Yeah, Repair Discretize Region takes lots of time . As `AbsoluteTiming@RepairMesh@DiscretizeRegion@r3` much faster than `AbsoluteTiming@RepairMesh@r3`.