# RegionIntersection not work, only outputs BooleanRegion Object

Tags: finite-element-method, regions, visualization, opencascade

This is an example to make Pi in 3D dimension

*Thanks @xzczd for providing the fast version. Link [Smoothing the Region？](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230725/smoothing-the-region/230735?noredirect=1#comment585308_230735)*

```
r = RegionProduct[#, Line[{{0.}, {10.}}]] &@
        ImageMesh@ColorNegate@ImageResize[Rasterize[" \[Pi]"], 100];
r2 = TransformedRegion[r, TranslationTransform[-RegionCentroid@r]];
r3 = RegionUnion@
        Table[TransformedRegion[RepairMesh@r2, 
        RotationTransform[i, {0, 1, 0}]], {i, -Pi/6, Pi/6, Pi/75}];
cy = DiscretizeRegion@Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 15];
RegionIntersection[r3, cy]
```

[image]

The visualization failed, but `RegionEmbeddingDimension` shows the dimensions are same.

> `RegionIntersection` says: `RegionIntersection` is defined only for regions with the same `RegionEmbeddingDimension`:

```
{RegionDimension /@ {r3, cy}, RegionEmbeddingDimension /@ {r3, cy}}
(* Yes, Different dimension {{2, 3}, {3, 3}} *)
```

Also failed by repairing the mesh

```
cyrepair = RepairMesh@cy;
RegionIntersection[r3, cyrepair]
(* Not worked *)
{RegionDimension /@ {r3, cyrepair}, RegionEmbeddingDimension /@ {r3, cyrepair}}
(* {{2, 2}, {3, 3}} *)
```

However, the code works if all dimension of regions are same.

```
{RegionDimension /@ {r2, cy}, RegionEmbeddingDimension /@ {r2, cy}}
RegionIntersection[r2, cy]
(* {{3, 3}, {3, 3}} *)
```

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I currently have the same problem and cannot find a solution

Comment: Then I used Shapr3D on iPad....

Answer (score 4):

- For Version 13, 14,we can do such intersection all in `OpenCascade` package, need not use `RepairMesh` etc.
- In the original code, there is blank in the text `" π"`.

```
r = RegionProduct[#, Line[{{0.}, {10.}}]] &@
   ImageMesh@ColorNegate@ImageResize[Rasterize[" π"], 100];

ball = Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 15];
```

- 

```
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
bm0 = ToBoundaryMesh[r];
shape0 = 
  OpenCascadeShapeTransformation[OpenCascadeShape@bm0, 
   TranslationTransform[-RegionCentroid@r]];
shape1 = 
  OpenCascadeShapeUnion@
   Table[OpenCascadeShapeTransformation[shape0, 
     RotationTransform[i, {0, 1, 0}]], {i, -Pi/6, Pi/6, Pi/75}];
shape2 = OpenCascadeShape[ball];
shape12 = OpenCascadeShapeIntersection[shape1, shape2];
mesh1 = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh@shape1;
mesh12 = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh@shape12;
```

- The Blue-Cyan region is the intersection of the ball(Yellow) and the rotation region of π ( Magenta ).

```
{mesh1["Wireframe"[
    "MeshElementStyle" -> 
     Directive[Opacity[.1], FaceForm[Magenta], EdgeForm[]], 
    Lighting -> "ThreePoint"]], 
  mesh12["Wireframe"[
    "MeshElementStyle" -> Directive[FaceForm[Blue], EdgeForm[Cyan]], 
    Lighting -> "ThreePoint"]], 
  Graphics3D[{Opacity[.1], Yellow, ball}]} // Show
```

[image]